Hamburger span lines not the same thickness on different devices
I am creating a bootstrap 5 website and am adding an animated nav toggler #02 from this link
CSS for the hamburger line height:
 .btnMenu02 > span > span, .btnMenu02 > span::before, .btnMenu02 > span::after {
 display: block;
 width: 22px;
 height: 2px !important;
 margin:6px auto!important;
 content: '';
 background-color: var(--light);
 border-radius: 4px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

One issue that I have found is that the height of the span lines used to create a hamburger menu tend to vary and can be uneven on some mobile devices, like this. I have tried different values for the line height, such as px, em or rem but this did not help.
Has amnyone found a workaround with this very common but tricky resolution issue? I do not want to use an image bacuse of the animation.

Do the heights vary on zooming in or out?

No browser has needed those vendor prefixes in many years.

Yeah. Interestingly. the lines are affected by the zoom resolution. When I zoom to 50% n Firefox, it seems to fix the issue. So it seems to be a screen resolution thing.

Height is dependent on the element's content like text this is especially true for anemic inline elements like <span>. I'm pretty sure you don't text in a hamburger. Is suggest that you use 1px of padding if 2px width is what you want.

Adding padding instead of height to the span element has made a huge improvement! Thank you! Never thought to use padding for span elements!
